# balance of sub-wallet not in main wallet address (blockchain.com)

Tags: blockchain.info, pycoin

I'm quite new to bitcoins so apologies if i'm being a noob, but I'm very confused!

I have many sub-wallet which created with [pycoin](https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin/) command line.

for example, I created subwallet like this:

```
ku -a xpub -s 0/77 -a
```

my main bitcoin address and xpub is in [blockchain.com](https://www.blockchain.com/wallet).

after someone send BTC to my sub-wallet. I can check that is really confirmed ([wallet and transaction in blockchain.com](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/17M19EUWwu5vmoHAJwkerscfGA2M1QqQXc)).

But when i go to my wallet in blockchain.com i can'nt see this balance. where is my mistake and how can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wallet service or application will not be watching all possible derivation paths.  Yours at `0/77` is definitely not a standard derivation and you should not expect any wallet to pick up on transactions sent to addresses under that path.

Comment: thanks for your answer, what is your solution ?

Comment: Hard to say.  For signing with keys in non standard derivation paths you will have to go through a lot of manual steps.  The simplest solution might be to first obtain the master private key (xpriv), derive the private key at the same path and manually sign a transaction paying back to yourself to some address in the standard derivation path.  This is not easy, error prone, and even dangerous if the xpub and the single private key are known by a 3rd party.  If you can get the private key for the address in `0/77`, you could try importing it in Electrum wallet and see if it find the transaction

Comment: what is best derivation path for blockchain.com ? is there any example or document for that ?

Comment: I don't know how their setup works, sorry.  Never used their services.